# WSO2 BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I migrated API manager to 2.1.0 version and i receive the following error.I used the same certificate which i used for identity server and its supposed to work.How can I find out what is causing this issue?Which file can i check?

```
[2018-05-08 04:46:50,601]  WARN - FileSystemPreferences Could not lock System prefs. Unix error code 1.
[2018-05-08 04:46:50,601]  WARN - FileSystemPreferences Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.
[2018-05-08 04:47:04,287]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2018-05-08 04:47:09,272] ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
```

I am using custom jks called mycert.jks... I am replacing the wso2carbon.jks with mycert.jks in all the places where keystore name is used... May be there is some place which i shouldnt change or i should change?

Answer (score 0):

`Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown` This should be be due to API Manager server couldn't verify the received certificate. (while calling the Identity Server maybe). If the received certificate is not CA signed, APIM server is unable to verify it without having their certificate in the client-truststore already.

As mentioned, you've replaced **wso2carbon.jks** with **mycert.jks**. Please make sure you've done the following as well.

1. Extract/import the public certificate from the new private key and add/export it in to the API Manager server's client-truststore.jks. `keytool -export -alias certalias -keystore newkeystore.jks -file <public key name>.pem` `keytool -import -alias certalias -file <public key name>.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon`
2. You have to set the same password for key store and key it self.

If the problem still persists add the SSL debug logs following [this](https://medium.com/@dilsimchandrasena/how-to-enable-ssl-debug-logs-for-wso2-products-6de7276ffe10). These logs will expose more information on where and what exactly the issue is.